# Converting road segments into one full link and taking mean of traffic volume

Tags: arcmap, volume, traffic, link, segment

I have road segments and want to convert them into one link (intersection to intersection). Image 1 shows the segments.

[image]

The biggest issue is that each link has traffic volume and when converted to links (one single line from one intersection to the other) the value of traffic volume for the link needs to be the mean of individual traffic volumes.

It should come out as one segment with the mean of all the volumes between two intersections.

[image]

Comment: Is there a segmentID on the road features such that all features on the same segment have the same ID?  Should the `mean` be weighted by length?

Comment: the mean should not be weighted by length. Unfortunately, the only common ID they have is the route name. so two or many links would have the same route name but are separated by an intersection.

Comment: This is a very common, but nontrivial, step in preparing GIS data for HPMS.  A search for `hpms gis segment merge` turns up [this](https://gis-t.transportation.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/51/2018/05/TMC-in-HPMS_03212018.pdf)

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Does this specify the solution to the problem? I went through it... is there a specific page number of methodology you are pointing me towards?

Comment: I don't know of any high level description, if you want code solution, maybe look here.  In case you have to deal with gaps.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/119159/59

Answer (score 1):

This can be **mostly** resolved with a simple dissolve.

This is your starting situation:

[image: network]
*Line direction is indicated by arrow, lines are labelled with volume and green points are the end nodes of a line*

If you ran this through the Dissolve tool as set up as below:

[image: tool]

You end up with this which for most of the network is exactly what you want BUT...

[image: Result]

*Lines colour coded by polyline ID, red label is mean volume.*

If you read the help file for the Dissolve tool for the Unsplit lines parameter it says it dissolves when only 2 are joined. I highlight to end points in blue which *may* be a junction and the third road is simply not shown for what ever reason so it erroneously dissolves it. But if this really was a loop in the network then the mean volume would be OK.